# WPF - Updating Elements While Long Operation Is Running In The Background

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, dispatcher

I am building a simple WPF app and in many places in the app I have long operation during which I would like to update the UI so that it doesn't look like the app crashed.
For example I have a Login button, and when I press it, in addition to verifying all the credentials, it also loads a binary Database of that specific user's data. The for a user with a lot of data, it can take about 3-5 seconds, for another it might be instant.

What I want is to be able to update other elements before completing the Button Click event, and I want to do it in the exact order of the code.

Here is the Login button click event:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var username = txtUsername.Text;
            var password = pswBox.Password;
            lblLoginStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) {
                lblLoginStatus.Content = "Both username and password cannot be empty!";
            } else {
                prgLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Progress bar that should be visible while the long operation is running.
                var login = Adb.Login(username, password); //Long operation
                prgLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Upon completion of the operation, hide the progress bar.
                if (!login) {
                    lblLoginStatus.Content = "Wrong Credentials!";
                } else { //This basically exits the login page/window
                    LoginPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    GeneralPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see I am not looking at any fancy animation or even progress report. The progress bar is indeterminate and I styled it so it just starts and ends with the Visibility trigger.

My issue is that against my logic that code runs literally in the same order as it is written, after the button is being pressed, It just looks stuck and no other elements are updated until the operation is over, at which point the login window hides itself, making all my efforts to create a pleasant UI worthless.

I have tried using:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(/*Whatever element update I want*/);
```

But it didn't help, the result was the same...

I have seen some complex and long solution of similar questions online, and I tried to implement them even if only to test, I messed with it for about 4 hours now and to no avail.

Just as above the rest of my app is filled with parts like:

```
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
var operation = AnyLongOperation()
prgLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

So I am looking for a simple solution that I will be able to adapt across the entire app.

Comment: Calling `Adb.Login(username, password)` from the UI thread (as you do here) will block that thread and hence the UI. Make the Login method async and await it, or wrap it in an awaited Task.

Comment: @Clemens I tried to wrap it in a Task and then use Task.WaitAll(Task) but it was still getting stuck... The problem I think is that I need to have the result before the Event exits for validation, if I use async await, while it awaits, it continues all other UI operations?

Comment: Yes. Make the handler method async, i.e. `private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`, then call `var login = await Task.Run(() => Adb.Login(username, password));`

Comment: @Clemens I thought you should do `var operation = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Adb.Login(username, password));` and then `var login = await operation;` or are they the same?

Comment: You would only use Task.Factory.StartNew under special circumstances. Use Task.Run, as said.

Comment: @Clemens so just that one line? it will both start and wait for the result?

Comment: Sure. Why do you think it should not be like that? You may also just search the internet for more info...

Comment: I don't think it shouldn't be like that, I was asking to better understand how it works... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the UI freezes because your program run on one single thread, `Adb.Login` blocks the main thread so the UI cannot be updated, you have to move your Login function into another thread and update the progress from there, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1) should help, it's not too complicated to implement or just make the login method async

Comment: You would neither explicity run a Thread, nor use a BackgroundWorker nowadays. Async/await is the way to go.